# Python - Check password (Weak/Strong/Very.Strong)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm starting python language and I wanted to try a quick thing.

```
inputpass = input("Choose a password?")


def passcheck(password):
    x = 0
    low = False
    cap = False
    hasnum = False
    while x < len(password):
        letter = password[x]
        if letter == letter.lower() and not letter.isnumeric():
            low = True
        elif letter == letter.upper():
            cap = True
        if letter.isnumeric():
            hasnum = True
        else:
            cap = False
            low = False
            hasnum = False
        x += 1
    if cap and low:
        print("You password is strong!")
    elif cap and not low or low and not cap:
        print("You password is weak!")
    elif cap and low and hasnum:
        print("You password is Very Strong!")
    else:
        print("You password is weak!")


passcheck(inputpass)
```

This is a script that checks input and says whether it is weak or strong but I'm doing something wrong, (I know of the `re` module but I would like to stick with this at the moment until I can do this without any error.

Comment: `if letter.isnumeric():
            ...
        else:...` is weird. You are basically saying that anytime you encounter a character that is not numeric, you consider that there are no lowercase, uppercase, or numerics in your password. Just remove that part, it does not make sense.

Comment: also, the testing part to indicate the strength is not in the right order. `if cap and low:` prevents `elif cap and low and hasnum:` to ever be verified.

Comment: I would test using `sum((cap, low, hasnum))` That gives you the number of tested conditions. 3 is good, 2 is ok, less is not so good.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but your password checker does **not** measure password strength very well, for example; for example, it will claim that `Passw0rd` is a "very strong" password (it is piss-poor, and any password cracker will quickly break it). It will also claim that "hallo dit is een wachtwoord dat vrij lang is and partly in dutch kthxbye" is a "weak" password. It is not. The folks at DropBox wrote a nice article about this: https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/

Answer (score 3):

A shorter and more readable way of handling a test on every character of a string:

```
cap = any(chr.isupper() for chr in password)
low = any(chr.islower() for chr in password)
hasnum = any(chr.isnumeric() for chr in password)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this worked perfectly (sorry for the (very) late response)

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
>>> import string
>>> def strong(s):
...     if len(list(set(s)&set(string.ascii_lowercase)))>0 and len(list(set(s)&set(string.ascii_uppercase)))>0 and len(list(set(s)&set(string.digits)))>0 and len(list(set(s)&set(string.punctuation)))>0:
...         return "Strong"
...     else: return "Weak"
... 
>>> strong("Hello?baby1")       # all good
'Strong' 
>>> strong("Hello?baby")        # no mumeric
'Weak' 
>>> strong("?baby")             # no uppercase, no  numeric
'Weak'
>>> strong("ljvjdl48?H")        # all good
'Strong'
>>> strong("hello how are you") # no numeric,no uppercase, no punctuation
'Weak'
```